# Implementing graph in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, graph

I have an application that captures analog signal data from external sensor which is sent into database. I have to use the data from the database to plot graph. And I don't know how to do it. Can anyone guide me in this?

Answer (score 2):

The best graphing library that I like to use is [coreplot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to write your own graphing tool, you will have to resort to 3rd party tools. Core Plot is a popular one.

[Check out 'core-plot'](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

Answer (score 1):

CorePlot is one of the charting library.

Other if you want to refer are as follows:

Some of the alternatives that I found were:

http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/

http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/

http://www.rgraph.net/

http://www.ivisualization.com/

http://www.vvi.com/apps/vvidget

http://github.com/duivesteyn-enterprises/deSimpleChart.

I hope this helps someone who is looking for alternatives to Core Plot.